# How to keep access_token parameter from login for next post requests

Tags: swagger

In swagger With api 3 version I have login described as :

```
  /login:
    post:
      tags:
        - user login
      summary: User login

      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful login
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/UserLogin'
        '400':
          description: Invalid login

      operationId: postLogin
      requestBody:
        description: Login user fields
        required: true
        content:
          application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                email:
                  type: string
                  default: admin@site.com
                password:
                  type: string
                  default: 111111
              required:
                - email
                - password
```

and if login is successfull amonth returned data I have access_token field.

With schema described as :

```
components:
  schemas:


    UserLogin:
      properties:
        access_token:
          type: string
        user:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/UserLogin'
        token_type:
          type: string
        user_avatar_path:
          type: string
        usersGroups:
          type: array
        expires_in:
          type: integer
```

I need to use this access_token value for next post requests to get access to authorized pages.

How can I do this in swagger. Seems I can not copypaste access_token value from login requeest for
my post requests, asthey do not access_token parameter ?

**MODIFIED BLOCK:**
I found how to copypaste access_token from login : https://prnt.sc/rs3ck6

/personal/profile url to read profile data has no in params in qiuery, so I defined access_token as :

```
  securitySchemes:
    ApiKeyAuth:        # arbitrary name for the security scheme
      type: apiKey
      in: header       # I suppose it must be "header"
      name: access_token
```

But how to add access_token to header of my /personal/profile ?
I see : https://prnt.sc/rs3i90
and clciking on button with Lock sign I see modal dialog “Available authorizations”, which is empty.
I suppose I have to select access_token from it?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible what I want ? If yes, how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is in my mind is [API Keys authentication](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/api-keys/). This will reduce times you need to copy paste your `access_token`.

Assume you need to pass `access_token` via query string on each `POST` request, then you could set up authentication globally in swagger like this:

```
components:
  securitySchemes:
    ApiKeyAuth:
      type: apiKey
      name: access_token
      in: header
security:
  - ApiKeyAuth: []
```

or, if you are using Bearer authentication:

```
components:
  securitySchemes:
    bearerAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer

security:
  - bearerAuth: []
```

After you get an `access_token` from `/login` call, you could click **Authorize** button under API information, and set it there. Then all the subsequent calls made via Swagger UI should automatically have `access_token` in the query string like this:

```
https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/login?access_token=1234
```

Comment: Thanks, but in provided link I do not see securityDefinitionsgroup. Is it just a sample ? I see securitySchemes ...

Comment: @PetroGromovo my bad `securityDefinitions` is v2, you should use `securitySchemes` in the docs.

Comment: You need that `security` in your swagger file as well. In your case, it will be `ApiKeyAuth: []`.

Comment: Yes, I added access_token parameter (as headerparam)in ApiKeyAuth(under security group).
I show code above 
I see in profile description button with Lock sign : https://prnt.sc/rs3i90
But clicking on it I see empty “Available authorizations” modal page, 
but it is empty : https://prnt.sc/rs6lw3
Did I miss some steps ?

Comment: Can you try updated answer? It worked for me in swagger editor http://editor.swagger.io/.

Comment: I tried to follow it and seems have the same data : https://prnt.sc/rs7uho
and request results : https://prnt.sc/rs7wmx
looks like access_token is not in the profile requesy.
Do you have this modal page : https://prnt.sc/rs7y2u
empty at your side ?

Comment: Now it’s clear the `api_key` under `security` should be `ApiKeyAuth` in your case. It should match the security schema.

Comment: I fixed and with it : see that for any request access_token is attatched
Also I see it in reproduced curl : https://prnt.sc/rs9hps
But anyway 401 error : https://prnt.sc/rs9kgp
Looks I still missed something?

Comment: How is auth implemented by your POST method? Does it understand using the access token header?

Comment: That is GET request.
the request from client app looks like : https://imgur.com/a/n6v6GMP
its access_token looks different and seems that is the issue ?
How how can I set in Swagger options?
In my client app I set it : 
                this.credentialsConfig.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + this.currentLoggedUserToken;
?

Comment: Then you could do `Bearer` schema: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/, or see updated answer